# How to store addess of a string and address of a function in a array?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to build a virtual function table. In an array I am storing the string(function name) and address of the function itself. I have googled for it. I was unable to find the solution?

```
char *arr[][] = { 
                 { "add", 0 },
                 { "sub", 0 },
                 { "div", 0 }
                };
int (*fp[3])(int, int) = {NULL};

fp[0] = &add;
fp[1] = &sub;
fp[2] = &div;
for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
    arr[0][i] = fp[i];
}
```

I am not able to store the address in the array. Could anyone have a look at my code?

Comment: You can't. Arrays are made to store only one kind of data. What you're looking for is *structures*.

Comment: Also, in your loop you're using the indexes wrong. It should probably be `arr[i][1]`.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. The array is of type char * so there is a chance of storing the integer pointer which is an address.

Comment: in the place of 0 i.e arr[0][0] the addresses should be stored

Comment: @user1624109  but function pointers are not of type `char *`, that's why you have to use an array of structures.

Comment: Normally virtual function tables don't store names. Why do you think you need them?

Comment: `char *arr[][] ` is illegal, you meant `char *arr[][2]`.  (Although this entire approach cannot work at all, of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is create an **array of structs**, aka creating your own abstract data type, which contains one item per entry, which contains all the possible data you could need. In the code you posted, you were creating a 2d `char` array and trying to store mixed data in it (not a good idea).

In your case, at the minimum, you need a function pointer and a function string/name. I also added a "function symbol", to help keep any possible string output contained within the `struct`.

I've included a sample of a previous, similar such exercise I've already done in the past.

Please note that in this example, it is using **integer division**. If you're not already familiar with the pitfalls of such an operation, you should really read up on it. I've included a link to a good read on it in the **References** section at the bottom of my post.

Good luck!

**Code Listing**

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor Directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_FCNS  (3)
/*******************************************************************************
 * Abstract Data Types
 ******************************************************************************/
/* Type alias for a pointer to a function that returns an int and takes
 * two int variables as arguments
 */
typedef int (*fp)(int, int);

typedef struct fcnEntry_t {
   fp          fcnPtr;
   const char* fcnName;
   const char  fcnSymbol;
} fcnEntry_t;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Protocols
 ******************************************************************************/
int add(int a, int b);
int sub(int a, int b);
int div(int a, int b);

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
int add(int a, int b) {
   return (a+b);
}

int sub(int a, int b) {
   return (a-b);
}

int div(int a, int b) {
   int ret;
   if (b == 0) {
      ret = 0;
   } else {
      ret = a / b;
   }
   return ret;
}

/*******************************************************************************
 * Main program entry point
 ******************************************************************************/
int main(void) {
   int i, a, b;
   /* Populate list of function pointer entries */
   fcnEntry_t  fcnTable[NUM_FCNS] = {
      {add, "addition",    '+'},
      {sub, "subtraction", '-'},
      {div, "division",    '/'}
   };

   /* Test all function table entries and log output/results */
   for (i=0, a=4, b=5; i<NUM_FCNS; i++) {
      printf("Function Name:%s a:%d b:%d\n", fcnTable[i].fcnName, a, b);
      printf("Result of %d %c %d = %d\n", a, fcnTable[i].fcnSymbol, b, fcnTable[i].fcnPtr(a,b));
   }

   /* Done */
   return 0;
}
```

**Sample Run**

---

```
Function Name:addition a:4 b:5
Result of 4 + 5 = 9
Function Name:subtraction a:4 b:5
Result of 4 - 5 = -1
Function Name:division a:4 b:5
Result of 4 / 5 = 0
```

**References**

---

1. *What is the behavior of integer division in C?*, Accessed 2014-07-20, [`<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define F(f_name, op) int f_name(int a, int b) { return a op b; }

F(add, +)
F(sub, -)
F(div, /)
//note : div function already exists in <stdlib.h>
enum { ADD, SUB, DIV};

struct vf {
    char *name;
    int (*fp)(int, int);
} vft[] = {
    { "add", add },
    { "sub", sub },
    { "div", div }
};

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", (vft[SUB].fp)(5,2));//3
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. (illustrates specifically how to improve OP code to answer question) - Would be even better with some descriptive comments.

Comment: Defining your own `div` causes undefined behaviour even if you didn't include `stdlib.h` and didn't call it. An easy fix is to prepend a unique string to the function name.

Comment: I wrote a note already. Supposed to be brought to light in the linker perhaps if there is a collision.